# Using gems in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am new to Ruby and Rails so this question might be trivial, but

How can you include/use a gem in Rails?

Do you just put "gem '

What do you do after that?

If this procedure is correct, when I try to run 'rails server' it spits out this error

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/gdata-1.1.1/lib/gdata.rb:21:in `require': no such file to load -- jcode (LoadError)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Ruby 1.9.2
Rails 3
RubyGem 1.3.7
Gem i'm trying to use 'contacts' 1.2.4

Thanks guys,
Sean Chan

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue, here is how I fixed it:

In case you havent already, put `gem 'contacts'`
 in your `Gemfile` and run

> bundle install

Ruby >= 1.9 doesn't have jcode, a module to handle japanese (EUC/SJIS) strings, as it supports unicode natively.

So you will need to add: `require 'jcode' if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9'` to your `gdata gem` found under your `.rvm` directory somewhere similar to this:

> /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@your_gemset_name/gems/gdata-1.1.1/lib/gdata.rb

change `line 21` to:

```
if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9'
  require 'jcode'
  $KCODE = 'UTF8'
end
```

As I'm also a noob how would I go about letting the author of the gdata gem know about this?

Comment: I was struggling to start rails server for last couple of hours.. this is awesome solution... thanks

Answer (score 8):

To use a Gem in Rails 3 you need to specify it in the `Gemfile` and use bundler to install the dependency. Here's a few resources to learn more about Bundler and Rails 3

- [Checking out the Rails 3 Beta, Part I: Bundler](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2010/03/30/checking-out-the-rails-3-beta-part-i-bundler/)
- [Bundler Website](http://gembundler.com/)
- [Bundler RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/201-bundler)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Updated to ruby 1.9.2 and the problem stopped.